# Incrementing an integer in a controller with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm not sure how to increment an integer in the controller

This is the what I tried. I'm grabbing the code, adding one and then saving it. This generates the error: "Call to a member function save() on string"

I'm returning the count to see the results in the browser. Running     $count = Count::find(1)->count in Tinker gives the correct amount.

```
public function update(Request $request, Count $count)
{
    $count = Count::find(1)->count;

    $addOne = $count + 1;

    $count->save();

    return ($count);
}
```

Could someone show me how this is not working and what I can do to fix this?

This is the migration:

```
 public function up()
  {
     Schema::create('counts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('count');
        $table->timestamps();
     });
 }
```

This is the Modal:

```
  <?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class Count extends Model
  {
      protected $fillable = [
        'count'
      ];
  }
```

Comment: why not simply use `$count++`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are storing the count property, not the object itself.

```
$count = Count::find(1);

$count->count += 1;

$count->save();

return ($count);
```

Should do the trick.

Some more defined naming might help as well. Had to do some mental gymnastics to wrap my head around what count I was counting.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is good, but this could be achieved even easier with the helper method that Laravel provides.

so this code:

```
$count = Count::find(1);
$count->increment('count');

return $count;
```

will do the same.

Comment: how is this easier than the accepted answer ??

Comment: fewer lines :) more readable on what you are doing, you don't have to agree with my definition of easier though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
  $count = Count::find(1);
  $count->count += 1;
  $count->save();
  return $count;
```